# IOS : Building Fails

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, build-process

I am a new IOS developer. I tried creating many iOS projects in Xcode, but all shows Build Failed errors. With HelloWorld, I could get it was related to AutoLayout - I unselected and that was it.

With this other project, I can't make out the reason for errors. The errors are :`
Build target CorporateChat

```
 CompileC /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CorporateChat-
    egudgkrhstksmbhhcldjmempbwsj/Build/Intermediates/CorporateChat.build/Debug-iphonesimulator
    /CorporateChat.build/Objects-normal/i386/TC_LoginDataController.o 
    CorporateChat/TC_LoginDataController.m normal i386 objective-c 
    com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler

        cd "/Users/admin/Documents/Kush InfoSystems/IOS Project/CorporateChat"

        setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
        setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform
    /Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:
    /sbin"

        /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
     -x objective-c -arch i386 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-
    backtrace-limit=0 -std=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -fmodules -fmodules-cache-path=/Users/admin/Library
    /Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-
    initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror=return-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties 
    -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=objc-root-class -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wno-arc-
    repeated-use-of-weak -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch 
-Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value 
-Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants 
-Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wshorten-
64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-
selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DDEBUG=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk -fexceptions 
-fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -Wno-sign-conversion -fobjc-
abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -mios-simulator-version-min=7.0 -iquote /Users/admin/Library
/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CorporateChat-egudgkrhstksmbhhcldjmempbwsj/Build/Intermediates
/CorporateChat.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CorporateChat.build/CorporateChat-generated-files.hmap 
-I/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CorporateChat-egudgkrhstksmbhhcldjmempbwsj/Build
/Intermediates/CorporateChat.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CorporateChat.build/CorporateChat-
own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CorporateChat-
egudgkrhstksmbhhcldjmempbwsj/Build/Intermediates/CorporateChat.build/Debug-iphonesimulator
/CorporateChat.build/CorporateChat-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/admin/Library/Developer
/Xcode/DerivedData/CorporateChat-egudgkrhstksmbhhcldjmempbwsj/Build/Intermediates/CorporateChat.build
/Debug-iphonesimulator/CorporateChat.build/CorporateChat-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/admin/Library
/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CorporateChat-egudgkrhstksmbhhcldjmempbwsj/Build/Products/Debug-
iphonesimulator/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains
/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
/CorporateChat-egudgkrhstksmbhhcldjmempbwsj/Build/Intermediates/CorporateChat.build/Debug-
iphonesimulator/CorporateChat.build/DerivedSources/i386 -I/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode
/DerivedData/CorporateChat-egudgkrhstksmbhhcldjmempbwsj/Build/Intermediates/CorporateChat.build
/Debug-iphonesimulator/CorporateChat.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode
/DerivedData/CorporateChat-egudgkrhstksmbhhcldjmempbwsj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator 
-include /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CorporateChat-egudgkrhstksmbhhcldjmempbwsj
/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/CorporateChat-Prefix-eiiyuowfsnsnqidczavfrfsfvsrz
/CorporateChat-Prefix.pch -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
/CorporateChat-egudgkrhstksmbhhcldjmempbwsj/Build/Intermediates/CorporateChat.build/Debug-
iphonesimulator/CorporateChat.build/Objects-normal/i386/TC_LoginDataController.d --serialize-
diagnostics /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CorporateChat-
egudgkrhstksmbhhcldjmempbwsj/Build/Intermediates/CorporateChat.build/Debug-iphonesimulator
/CorporateChat.build/Objects-normal/i386/TC_LoginDataController.dia -c /Users/admin/Documents/Kush\ 
InfoSystems/IOS\ Project/CorporateChat/CorporateChat/TC_LoginDataController.m -o /Users/admin/Library
/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CorporateChat-egudgkrhstksmbhhcldjmempbwsj/Build/Intermediates

/CorporateChat.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CorporateChat.build/Objects-normal

/i386/TC_LoginDataController.o

    fatal error: file '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform
    /Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/usr/include/objc/NSObject.h' has been modified since the 
    precompiled header '/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/1X5NZJEZL1PED
    /ObjectiveC.pcm' was built

    note: after modifying system headers, please delete the module cache at '/Users/admin/Library
    /Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/1X5NZJEZL1PED'
    1 error generated.
```

I am getting such 5 errors with SBJasonStreamWriterAccumelator.m, SBJasonStreamParserAccumelator.m, SBJasonStreamParseState.m, SBJasonWriter.m and one of my implementation class. I have just added SBJason to the project, not implemented any feature.

Can anyone please help me get my project build succeed. From start I am getting Build Failed only. My motto is I want the app to execute on most of the platforms - s oI plan to support from 4 to latest i.e. 7. Am I missing or need any corrections in any project settings !!

Do I need to do any setting changes or what's causing this errors. Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Try to clean the project and run again.

Comment: "NSObject.h has been modified...".  That's nasty and should never happen, unless you've changed versions of Xcode recently, in which case a clean should sort it out.

Comment: From taking a quick look at the error message, it seems you’re having path problems. Have you added the SBJason files to the Copy Phase in your Buildsettings? Also a clean project is always nice. ;)

Comment: have you tried what you get proposed in the last line? -- please delete the module cache at '/Users/admin/Library
    /Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/1X5NZJEZL1PED'

Comment: Delete all derived data(/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData). clean. Build again.

Comment: I deleted the DerivedData, Clean, exited Xcode, Opened Xcode, Clean and finally Build. But yet I get those errors. This time their are 4 in place of 5 - SBJsonStreamWriterAccumulator, SBJsonStreamParserAccumulator, SBJsonStreamParserState & my 1 .m files. I added SBJson class files to the project via Xcode. I haven't opened or modified any NSObject.h or other system class.

Comment: rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to all friends.
Nothing above helped, but certain changes in Project & Build settings helped me solve the problem.

I changed the following and then got Build Succeeded.
* Deployment Target - changed from 7 to 6.0
In Build Settings :-
* Base SDK - from "Latest iOS 7.0" to "iOS 7.0"
* iOS Deployment Target - Changed from 7.0 to iOS 6.0

Shared me solution as it might help someone else like me.

Wondering why changing from 7.0 to 6.0 worked ??? Does this mean that 7.0 is not stable or compatible ??

Comment: same here, don't why its working with changing deployment target to 6.0